# Cancelling inheritance for a component not working

Tags: inheritance, aem, blueprint-osgi, rollout

I am currently working on an AEM 6.2 project.
When we disable inheritantce  on a livecopy component and change it’s value (e.g title),  then we re-enable inheritantce on this livecopy component, it does not pull value from it’s blueprint component.

For example, please take a look on this screenshot:
[image]

On the blueprint component, we have title value "From blueprint changed again"
On the livecopy component, we disabled inheritantce and changed title value to "From blueprint changed again 2222"

Now, we switch it back enable the inheritantce, please see below screenshot:

[image]

Now we expect the livecopy component title to be revert back to "From blueprint changed again", but it is not happening, it does not pull the value from it blueprint anymore.

So I am not sure this is a AEM6.2 product bug or not, I am using the default geometrixx site to create this example to show here.
Any advise and suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the inheritance is enabled the data will be still loaded from the blueprint, and that's why your dialog is in disabled state. **And the data you are seeing in the dialog is from the component node stored (which is nothing but previous edited) which will not be updated until you rollout again**.

For your problem if you rollout the component alone, you should be able to see the data in the dialog field also.

Comment: hi var, the 'cancel inheritent' is really an out of box feature, in cq 5 , if you cancel the inheritant, the component immediately pulled the value from blueprint.  it is only in aem6.2 , ref to this link-> https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/release-notes/sites.html     (• Starting AEM 6.2, reverting inheritance does not anymore automatically trigger a rollout. The modified behavior after reverting inheritance now allows to review changes in a blueprint before rolling them out to live copies. (CQ-64894))

Comment: i am not very sure about  what adobe says " The modified behavior after reverting inheritance now allows to review changes in a blueprint before rolling them out to live copies."    any suggestions?

Comment: As per the Adobe Docs, **The modified behavior after reverting inheritance now allows to review changes in a blueprint before rolling them out to live copies** 
means that if you revert back to inheritance still the changes exists in the component level for a review and break inheritance if required without further editing, until next roll out from blueprint to live copies.

Comment: so in aem6.2 when I cancelled the inheritant on component level,  I have to do the 'rollout' action on the blueprint page mannually?  anything that I can config to alter 6.2 behaviour like CQ5.6 -> cancel inheritant on component -> auto pull values from blueprints ?